# creating sticker packs using pyrogram

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

How do I create sticker packs and add stickers to them using Pyrogram raw functions and my Telegram bot? I attempted to use Pyrogram.raw functions, but encountered errors. I've consulted the documentation, reviewed examples, and searched Pyrogram's official group, but haven't found a solution. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution that I hope it to be useful for you too. here is the custom function I've written

```
def create_or_add_sticker(user_id, document, emojis, title, short_name) -> raw.base.messages.StickerSet:
    media = (bot.invoke(UploadMedia(
        peer=bot.resolve_peer('stickers'),
        media=InputMediaUploadedDocument(
            mime_type="image/png",
            file=(bot.save_file(document)),
            force_file=True,
            thumb=None,
            attributes=[DocumentAttributeFilename(file_name=document)])))
    ).document

    sticker = InputStickerSetItem(document=InputDocument(id=media.id, access_hash=media.access_hash, file_reference=media.file_reference), emoji=emojis)

    try:
        result = bot.invoke(CreateStickerSet(user_id=InputUser(user_id=user_id, access_hash=bot.resolve_peer(user_id).access_hash), title=title, short_name=short_name, stickers=[sticker]))
    except:
        stickerset: raw.base.messages.StickerSet = bot.invoke(GetStickerSet(stickerset=InputStickerSetShortName(short_name=short_name), hash=0))
        if stickerset.set.count == 120:
            stdt = stickerset.documents[-2]
            bot.invoke(
                RemoveStickerFromSet(sticker=InputDocument(id=stdt.id, access_hash=stdt.access_hash, file_reference=stdt.file_reference))
                        )
        result = bot.invoke(AddStickerToSet(stickerset=InputStickerSetShortName(short_name=short_name), sticker=sticker))
    return result
```